# Output iterator that only counts the number of increments?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator

In STL/Boost, is there a ready-made output iterator that only counts the number of times it's incremented? When an algorithm does `*iter = value`, the value would simply be discarded.

If not, then rolling my own seems easy enough. Although it might be useful to others if someone posted an example of such an iterator.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Can you think of an example?

Comment: There's `std::count()` and `std::count_if()`. Will these do?

Comment: @wilhelm: Let's say I have an algorithm, `findArticulations`, that outputs the articulation points in a graph via an output iterator. I'd like to write another algorithm `isBiconnected` that makes use of the already existing `findArticulations`.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Yes, I suppose `std::count` could work in my example, but it would require that articulation points be needlessly copied to a temporary container only to be counted.

Comment: There's `boost::counting_iterator` but I'm not sure it does what you want. It yields the count with `operator*`.

Comment: @wilhelm: Yes, I think it'll work. Thanks! If you provide an answer below, I'll accept it.

Comment: @wilhelm: Upon further investigation, it seems that `boost::counting_iterator` will not work. It's read-only. :-( Thanks anyway. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such iterator exists in standard C++, and to the best of my knowledge no Boost iterator has this exact functionality.  There are plenty of ways that you could do this using those libraries without having to roll your own, though.  For example, using Boost's `function_output_iterator`, you could build a counter like this:

```
struct Counter {
    size_t* out;

    explicit Counter(size_t* where) : out(where) {
        // Handled in initializer list
    }

    /* Either make this a template, or make the class itself a template. */
    template <typename T> void operator()(T& value) {
        ++ *out;
    }
};
```

This functor type takes in a pointer to a counter variable, and then whenever its `operator()` is invoked increments the counter.  If you then wrap this in a `function_output_iterator`, as seen here:

```
size_t count;
your_algorithm(begin, end,
              boost::make_function_output_iterator(Counter(&count)));
```

Then whenever the created iterator is written to, your `operator()` will get called and the counter will get incremented.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 I bet there's a way to turn that into a one-liner using boost lambdas.

Comment: @Emile Cormier- I haven't tested this, but perhaps something like `boost::bind(++*_1, &count)` ?

Comment: This worked for me: `std::copy( ar.begin(), ar.end(), boost::make_function_output_iterator(++boost::lambda::var(n)) );`

Comment: @Emile Cormier: Cool!  Or, you could do the whole C++0x dealie of `[&count](/* ... type ... */) {++count}`. :-)

Comment: I'm gonna wait for the C++ gurus to finalize the C++0x spec before attempting to wrap my head around those newfangled lambdas. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Yep. In boost:

[The counting iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html)